# Couldn't find outer class com/razorpay/Y_$B$ of com/razorpay/Y_$B$$5

Tags: android, razorpay

I am implementing **RazorPay** android checkout. I followed [Razorpay Android sdk doc.](https://docs.razorpay.com/v1/page/android) When running app gradle build fails with this error. I have posted that on RazorPay also.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Couldn't find outer class com/razorpay/Y_$B$ of com/razorpay/Y_$B$$5
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:1079)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.ClassVsInterface.isOuterInterface(ClassVsInterface.java:56)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitOuterClass(InterfaceDesugaring.java:246)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:638)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)
```

**If some developer faced this issue, please tell me a solution.**

I have no code to show, its only picked from above razorpay doc.

Comment: Have  u got the answer?

Comment: @JanardhanR see answer!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution after searching a lot.

This issue occurred after updating to new Android Studio and `build:gradle`. **This is not RazorPay sdk issue.**

Similar issue is reported in **[google tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72750890#comment10)**

To solve this, just downgrade `build.gradle` version in your **project level build.gradle.**

```
buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        ...
    }
}
```

**This resolved my issue. Hope will do for you too.**

Comment: yes it worked when i downgraded version to 3.0.1 do you have idea why its was not working with 3.1.2

Comment: Internal bug of gradle version or sdk's are not updated still.

Comment: See google issue tracker link, you will get your answer there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding android.enableD8.desugaring = true to gradle.properties