# Build speed is too slow after adding "android.enableD8.desugaring=true"

Tags: android, build

I have added `android.enableD8.desugaring` to solve [some issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344132/couldnt-find-outer-class-com-razorpay-y-b-of-com-razorpay-y-b5).

However, the build speed slowed down too much. (3min -> 20min)

Question.

- What is `android.enableD8.desugaring`?
- What is the operating principle of `android.enableD8.desugaring`?
- Is it a factor to slow down the build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Self Answer***

The meaning of "android.enableD8.desugaring=true"  should be interpreted separately.

1. d8 : d8 is a command line tool that Android Studio and the Android Gradle Plugin use to compile your project's Java bytecode into DEX bytecode that runs on Android devices, and it allows you to use Java 8 language features in your app's code.
2. "desugaring = true" : You can use Java 8 language features. "Java 8 language features." It is understood as a lambda expression.

I guess d8 might be slower when compiling "Java 8 language features."

Reference 
: [d8 | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/d8)